# How to delay events for next observers?

Tags: android, events, design-patterns, event-handling, observer-pattern

```
override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {

    if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        val status = operation() // operation takes time
        return status
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
}
```

When an event occurs, the above handler gets called. Now if it requires time to decide whether to pass the `true` or `false` status to next layers (super) inside if block, how can the flow be designed properly. I am required to get the result `asynchronously` because the time to decide return value (i.e. `true` or `false`) might be longer and the function shouldn't keep main thread await. So, I need to find other way to make the super call delayed.

What is the proper way to get rid of this problem? Any specific design pattern to deal this kind of problem?

Please ignore the language.

### Update 1

I have been thinking to store `keyCode` and `event` and return `true` (means the event was consumed and no need to re consume by other observer) immediately, and then after `operation()` is completed i have the `status` available and now I can re trigger the pending stored event with same `keyCode` and `event`. But not all event provides functions to trigger manually. How can I do so for events that can not be triggered manually.

#### My proposed solution

```
private fun doOperation(callback: (status:Boolean) -> Unit) {
    Handler().postDelayed({
        callback.invoke( arrayOf(true, false).random() )
    }, 5000)
}

var pendingEvent: KeyEvent? = null

override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
    if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        doOperation {
            if (it && pendingEvent != null){
                dispatchKeyEvent(pendingEvent)
                pendingEvent = null
            } else {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
        return true // let other know I consumed it
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
}
```

Is this a proper way? What can be bad of this thought?

Comment: you mean that you  don't know if `onKeyDown` should return true or false?

Comment: @Blackbelt i will be knowing the return value after an asynchronous operation (lets say a server call from web-app) which requires a delay. But this is a f/w callback which needs to pass true or false in synchronously and immediately.

Comment: AFAIK, this isn't possible. You can't delay the return statement without blocking the main thread.

Comment: @karandeepsingh I know its not possible. I was looking for a way around.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You need to restructure your application. An event handler should never return a value. It doesn't make sense in the classic event concept. An event is just a notification and the notifier (observable) does not know what the observer is doing. Following this rule, you will _never_ run into a situation, where the observable has to block a thread or operation until a particular observer responds.

Comment: "Any specific design pattern to deal this kind of problem?" Just do the Observer Pattern" properly. In your case it looks like the observable, that raises the event, depends on a result of an operation that must execute on the specific event (key down). The observable already knows the moment when the event occurred, since he is the source of the event. Therefore the observable can directly execute the operation on his own and receive the result for further processing. After the observable is done he can notify all listeners (or notify them first and then execute own operations).

Comment: Because events are fire-and-forget (no return value or `void`) it should be clear that _asynchronous events_ are a contradiction in itself or a paradox. When asynchronous means "_waiting_ without blocking" and event "notify _without_ waiting" you are obviously creating more problems then solutions.

Comment: @BionicCode what if the observer needs more time to decide if it consumes or not? How do you deal it?

Comment: You have three options to wait: 1) Keep spinning until a condition is met like polling (e.g. infinite loop): `while(true){}`. 2) Use a timer and after the elapsed time do the action 3) Use events whenever you need to wait.  

The first two options will block a thread. If the thread is the same as the observable thread, than you are blocking the observable and all other waiting observers too. If that thread is an UI thread, then the UI will stall and become unresponsive.  
Events are a pattern that will solve the blocking issue.

Comment: So first everything that you might need to wait for, must have an event associated. Let's assume you are starting a specific animation depending on which a key was pressed _AND_ before you can start a new animation you have to wait until the first one completes. This are two waiting situations: key pressed and animation completed. Now you create and associate an event for each potential waiting situation: `keyPressed` and `animationStopped` event.

Comment: The situation is that the key is pressed before a possible running animation completes. So instead of making the event handler `onKeyPressed` wait until the animation completes, you would store the pressed key: `pressedKey = keyPressedEventArgs.getPressedKey();` and subscribe to the `animationCompleted` event. The `onKeyPressed` handler is now done.

Comment: Now after a minute the long running animation stopped and the `onAnimationStopped` handler is invoked. In this handler you first unsubscribe from the `animationStopped` event. Then check what key was pressed to decide which animation to start and start the appropriate new animation. Now you have waited without blocking anything. The result or event args of the first event was stored, so that the deferred operation (the event handler ònAnimationCompleted`) can use it later.

Comment: Always unsubscribe from an event. This way you can't forget it. Forgetting to unsubscribe can lead to memory leaks.

Comment: _"what if the observer needs more time to decide if it consumes or not? How do you deal it?"_ This decision (or decisions in general) depends _always_ on the state of at least one variable. Two situations: 1) the state is known at the moment the observer gets notified or 2) the state is unknown at this moment (the observer needs more time). Situation 1) requires no waiting, but 2) does. In this case the change of the state depends _always_ on a operation to complete. This operation determines how long the waiting time is. This operation must raise an event, when the relevant state has changed.

Comment: @BionicCode you are suggesting to store the event and fire after operation is completed? That is a good idea. Can you please describe with code snippet in answer so that i can mark as accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly. I meant to store the result of the event. The argument that the observable passes to the listener callback. I will provide a small example. No problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because events are fire-and-forget (no return value or void) it should be clear that asynchronous events or event handlers that return a value are a contradiction in itself or a paradox. When asynchronous means "waiting without blocking" and event "notify without waiting" you are obviously creating more problems than solutions. A return value also implies that the caller is waiting for completion of the operation and is interested in the result.

I recommend to restructure your application.
An event handler should never return a value or be asynchronous.

> what if the observer needs more time to decide if it consumes or not? 
>   How do you deal it?

This decision (or decisions in general) depends always on the state of at least one variable. 
There are two situations

1. the state is known at the moment the observer gets notified or
2. the state is unknown at this moment (the observer needs more time).

*Situation 1)* requires no waiting, but *situation 2)* does.
In case of *situation 2)*, the change of the state is always triggered by an operation. The execution duration of this operation determines how long the waiting time is. This operation must raise an event, when the relevant state has changed.

In general you have three options to wait:

1. Keep spinning until a condition is met like polling (e.g. infinite
   loop): while(true){}.
2. Use a timer and after the elapsed time do the action
3. Use events whenever you need to wait.

The first two options will block a thread. If the thread is the same as the observable thread, than you are blocking the observable and all other waiting observers too. If that thread is an UI thread, then the UI will stall and become unresponsive. Events are a pattern that will solve the blocking issue.

---

Let's imagine the following scenario: you want to start a specific animation. You have two constraints: the type of the animation depends on which a key was pressed AND before you can start a new animation you have to wait until the first one completes. E.g. when *TAB* was pressed move a rectangle from left to right. When *ENTER* was pressed move a rectangle from top to bottom.

This introduces two waiting situations: key pressed and animation completed. To handle the waiting, you would create and associate an event for each potential waiting situation: `keyPressed` and `animationStopped` event:

**The keyboard key pressed event**

The interface to be implemented by the observer that is waiting for a particular key to be pressed:

```
interface IKeyPressedListener {
  void onKeyPressed(int keyCode);
}
```

The event interface to be implemented by the observable that exposes and raises the event:

```
interface IKeyPressedEvent {
  void subscribeToKeyPressedEvent(IKeyPressedListener listener);
  void unsubscribeToKeyPressedEvent(IKeyPressedListener listener);
}
```

**The animation event**

The interface to be implemented by the observer that is waiting for an animation to stop:

```
interface IAnimationStoppedListener {
  void onAnimationStopped();
}
```

The event interface to be implemented by the observable that exposes and raises the event:

```
interface IAnimationStoppedEvent {
  void subscribeToAnimationStoppedEvent(IAnimationStoppedListener listener);
  void unsubscribeToAnimationStoppedEvent(IAnimationStoppedListener listener);
}
```

**The actual event listener**

The implementation of the class that plays an animation on key pressed:

```
class AnimationController implements IKeyPressedListener, IAnimationStoppedListener 
{
  // store the key that was pressed,
  // so that an event that will be raised at a later can process it
  private int keyCodeOfLastKeyPressed = 0;

  // The reference to the class that exposes
  // the keyPressedEvent by implementing IKeyPressedEvent 
  KeyboardController keyboardController;

  // The reference to the class that exposes
  // the animationStoppedEvent by implementing IAnimationStoppedEvent 
  AnimationPlayer animationPlayer;

  // Constructor
  public AnimationController() {
    this.keyboardController = new KeyboardController();
    this.animationPlayer = new AnimationPlayer();

    // Subscribe to the key pressed event
    this.keyboardController.subscribeToKeyPressedEvent(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onKeyPressed(int keyCode) {
    if (this.animationPlayer.hasPlayingAnimation) {
      // Instead of waiting that the animation completes
      // subscribe to an event and store the relevant data
      this.keyCodeOfLastKeyPressed  = keyCode;
      this.animationPlayer.subscribeToAnimationStoppedEvent(this);      
    }
    else {
      // There is no playing animation, so no need to wait
      this.animationPlayer.playAnimation(keyCode);
    }
  }

  // After a while this handler will be invoked by the event source.
  @Override
  public void onAnimationStopped() {
    // To avoid memory leaks unsubscribe first
    this.animationPlayer.unsubscribeToAnimationStoppedEvent(this);

    // Since we stored the key code earlier, we can continue to process it
    // and start a new animation that maps to a specific key
    this.animationPlayer.playAnimation(this.keyCodeOfLastKeyPressed);
  }
}
```

Following the Observer Pattern avoids thread blocking waiting time. The application can just leave the context and return when the event occurred (in this case the `AnimationStopped` event). To store the change value (event args) of an event, a private shared field is introduced, so that the second event handler can access and finally process it.

Comment: Thanks for such a descriptive answer. Could you please see my update and review my thought?

Answer (score 0):

Using Observer-pattern may help you.
`You can use Debounce operator (debounce(DEBOUNCE_TIMEOUT.toLong(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) to delay the event.
only emit an item from an Observable if a particular timespan has passed without it emitting another item`
[Check the official documentation for how to use](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html)

Edit 1
Code snippet

`RxView.clicks(mButton)
    .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(...)`

Comment: How can I use debounce in pure android? Any code snippet example? Thanks

Comment: Debounce is part of RxAndroid library.Please check the Edit 1 part of the answer.